# C# cannot convert Int to Double

Tags: c#

I get the error converting `Int` to `Double`, my next line `Average[y] = Average[y] + Students[i].Marks;` is not working either. So how can convert `int[]` to `double[]`?

```
public static double[] Averages(StudentMarks[] Students, int amount, string[] DifferentGroups, int GroupAmount, out double[] Average)
    {
        Average = new double[Max];
        int y = 0;
        int CountGroups = 0;
        //int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            if (Students[i].Group == DifferentGroups[y])
            {
                Convert.ToDouble(Students[i].Marks);
                //Average[y] = Average[y] + Students[i].Marks;
            }
        }
        return Average;
    }
```

The main:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int amount;
        StudentMarks[] Students;
        string[] DifferentGroups;
        int GroupAmount;
        double[] Average;
        ReadData(out Students, out amount);
        DifferentGroups = FindDifferentGroups(Students, amount, out DifferentGroups, out GroupAmount);
        Average = Averages(Students, amount, DifferentGroups, GroupAmount, out Average);
```

Class:

```
        public const int Max = 50;
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public int AmountOfMarks { get; set; }
    public int[] Marks { get; set; }
```

So Student[i].Marks is Array.

Comment: Is `Students[i].Marks` an array?

Comment: `Convert.ToDouble` _returns_ a double - it does not make an integer property a double.

Comment: actually I'm not sure whether it's array or not. probably not, give me a few seconds, i will edit the post.

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: If so, try `Average[y] += Students[i].Marks.Sum()`.

Comment: Thank you all, it worked !!!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what worked?

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToDouble` *returns* a double - it does not make an integer property or variable a double.

I think you want:

```
        if (Students[i].Group == DifferentGroups[y])
        {
            double mark = Convert.ToDouble(Students[i].Marks);
            Average[y] = Average[y] + mark;
        }
```

or just:

```
        if (Students[i].Group == DifferentGroups[y])
        {
            Average[y] = Average[y] + Convert.ToDouble(Students[i].Marks);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All `Convert.ToXXX` functions **return** the new value. Therefore, you should be expecting that and assigning the return value to a local variable.

Something like:

```
double YourMark = Convert.ToDouble(Students[i].Marks);
```

Answer (score 0):

> So how can convert int[] to double[]?

By programming. You write code to do it.

```
var d = new double[Students[i].Marks.Length];
for (int j = 0; j < Students[i].Marks.Length; ++j)
{
    d[j] = Convert.ToDouble(Students[i].Marks[j]);
}
```

Or use LINQ:

```
var d = Students[i].Marks.Select(n => Convert.ToDouble(n)).ToArray();
```

Next time a method call won't compile or doesn't work the way you hoped it might, a good first step would be to check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx).